# Key press event isn't fired

Tags: java, events, javafx, keypress

In a javaFY project, I want to add a key pressed listener to the whole window. The root node in the window's FXML file is:

```
<VBox onKeyPressed="#windowKeyPressed" fx:controller="hu.kleni.tetris.EventController" ...>
```

And hte event handler class:

```
public class EventController {
    @FXML
    public void windowKeyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event.getCode());
    }
    ...
}
```

In the `main()` method, It just loads and launches the window. If I start the program, the windows shows up, but after I press a key, I can't see anything in the console. Did I miss something?

Edit: Although I could use this (and it works fine):

```
scene.setOnKeyPressed((event) -> {
    // maybe call EventController.windowKeyPressed(event);
})
```

, I'd prefer to define all event handlers in only the FXML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need the `root` (`VBox`) to have focus for `onKeyPressed` to work.

In your `Application` class, `requestFocus()` on your `root` after the `Stage` is shown, e.g.:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));        
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    root.requestFocus(); // add this, root is the VBox in your case
}
```